# getting a 2d array with out knowing the size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to using pointers and I have a problem.
I must get a 2D array of characters from the user and the user is giving me the number of rows and columns and what the array should be filled with.

```
    int rows,col,i,j;
    char **array;
    int *storage;
    cin >> rows >> col;
    array = new *int[rows];
    storage = new int[rows*col];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        array[i] = storage + col * i;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            cin>>array[i][j];}
    }
```

I wrote the code above for it but it doesn't work.I tried searching for such thing but I didn't find anything.
can you help me to fix the error with this code please?

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should almost always be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Why do you use int for an array of characters?

Comment: As for your current code and the problem you have, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: manni66 I thought I must use int because of the size

Comment: Oh and whenever you want to read characters, you probably want to use them as *strings* in which case you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). In your case a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: What? `array = new *int[rows];`?

Comment: So, everyone has to guess, first, what your error is, before figuring out the reason for it. Or perhaps you would like to actually explain, explicitly, what your mysterious error is. Helpful tip: someone with more experience will often immediately know the reason for a specific error, but would not care to waste time figuring out what the original problem is in the first place. If your goal is to get an answer to your question, you must provide all relevant and pertinent information in the question itself. "It doesn't work" is not a useful explanation.

Comment: Hey, let's not be mean to the newbie. You can't know the size of a 2d array based solely on a stream of all the values, but your code gets the size, so now you already know. Just use that. The "not working" is not related to this, but rather to errors in the code. Please don't try to use pointers if you don't know c++; std::vector is recommended. Using raw pointers for your array is bad practice because they are error prone for people who do know c++.

Answer (score 0):

Array is static so use `vector` instead i.e `std:vector` it is dynamic so that 
you can enlarge the size of the vector during runtime.

Comment: std::array was not used. The thing called "array" in the OP was dynamic. I expect better if you want to post a one line answer which simply repeats what has been said in multiple comments.